# Web-based Python interpreter with explanations

Tags: python, interpreter

On reddit, I've seen a link to web site, which does not only interpret Python code, but also gives a graphical explanation of how the code is interpreted. I found this potentially very helpful for learning and teaching. Sadly, I don't remember the link.

Given code such as

```
A = []
B = A
B.append(1)
print A
print B
```

this website would show, how each line changes the state of the Python program. A user could see that A and B represent the same object and intuitively understand that the third line effects `print A` and `print B`

Comment: http://repl.it/ (via http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/klv3o/replit_a_clientside_web_repl_for_15_languages/)?

Comment: @MattBall: I doubt it - the app you linked to (repl.it) does not explain anything from Python code, it is only a web based Python interpreter (not mentioning other languages it can support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Online Python Tutor](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/) is probably what you want.